# traverse a json tree structure and add all nodes into a list

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, recursion, tree

So i have a json object that i would like to traverse and add all the nodes in a linear list.below is my json

```
    [{ "name" : "Joe", "age" : "21", "children" : [
        { "name" : "Smith", "age" : "42", "children" : [] },
        { "name" : "Gary", "age" : "21", "children" : [
            { "name" : "Jenifer", "age" : "23", "children" : [
                { "name" : "Dani", "age" : "32", "children" : [] },
                { "name" : "Max", "age" : "34", "children" : [] }
            ]}
        ]}
    ]},
    { "name" : "Albert", "age" : "33", "children" : [] },
    { "name" : "Ron", "age" : "29", "children" : [] }
];
```

and i want to create a list of all objects present in the tree, objects need to be like this:
 `{ "name" : "Joe", "age" : "21"}`

Comment: Odd that these people have children older than themselves 

Comment: Is there any ordering constraint? e.g. Joe is always the first, then followed by his descendants. This continues until no more children nodes are found until then the next node is Albert.

Comment: no ordering constraint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a recursive function is an easy to traverse and flatten your array. Here's a sample algorithim:

```js
function flatten(items, result = []) {
  if (items.length) {
    var item = items.shift();
    result.push(item);

    if (item.children && item.children.length) {
      result = flatten(item.children, result);
    }

    return flatten(items, result);
  } else {
    return result;
  }
}

var people = [{
  "name": "Joe",
  "age": "21",
  "children": [{
    "name": "Smith",
    "age": "42",
    "children": []
  }, {
    "name": "Gary",
    "age": "21",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Jenifer",
      "age": "23",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Dani",
        "age": "32",
        "children": []
      }, {
        "name": "Max",
        "age": "34",
        "children": []
      }]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "Albert",
  "age": "33",
  "children": []
}, {
  "name": "Ron",
  "age": "29",
  "children": []
}];

console.log(flatten(people));
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this would be to `transverse` your tree structure by using `recursive` function.

In my solution I make use of the `instanceOf` API to check what type of element the transverse is at and then determine what actions to be taken.

**See:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

**Example:**

```
let result = [];
let people =
    [
      { "name" : "Joe", "age" : "21", "children" : [
        { "name" : "Smith", "age" : "42", "children" : [] },
        { "name" : "Gary", "age" : "21", "children" : [
          { "name" : "Jenifer", "age" : "23", "children" : [
            { "name" : "Dani", "age" : "32", "children" : [] },
            { "name" : "Max", "age" : "34", "children" : [] }
          ]}
        ]}
      ]},
      { "name" : "Albert", "age" : "33", "children" : [] },
      { "name" : "Ron", "age" : "29", "children" : [] }
    ];

function transverse(element, result) {
    if (element instanceof Array)
      element.forEach(item => { transverse(item, result); });
    else if (element instanceof Object) {
      result.push({ name: element.name, age: element.age });
      if (element.hasOwnProperty("children")) {
        transverse(element.children, result);
      }
    }
}

transverse(people, result);
console.log(result);
```

**Output:**

```
[ { name: 'Joe', age: '21' },
  { name: 'Smith', age: '42' },
  { name: 'Gary', age: '21' },
  { name: 'Jenifer', age: '23' },
  { name: 'Dani', age: '32' },
  { name: 'Max', age: '34' },
  { name: 'Albert', age: '33' },
  { name: 'Ron', age: '29' } ]
```

Comment: @ua_boaz Just in case you met a similar problem in future, you can also consider this as an alternative solution. It basically walks the tree node by node and preserve ordering as well. It also has a little bit less code.

Comment: Hi Samuel, another question not sure if you can help... lets say i am trying to find parent of a object, i.e. { "name" : "Max", "age" : "34", "children" : [] }, it should return its parent node object, { "name" : "Jenifer", "a ... } any ideas for that?

Comment: @ua_boaz
Sure I can help. Do you want to raise another question and I will jump aboard with a solutioN?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a simple traversal with no sorting it can be accomplished with two simple functions:

```
function visitChild(node, array) {
    array[array.length] = { name: node.name, age:node.age };
    if (node.children && node.children.length) {
        node.children.forEach( function(child) { visitChild(child, array); } );
    }
}

function traverseTree(root, list = []) {
    if (root.length) {
        root.forEach( function(node){ visitChild(node, list); });
    }
    return list;
}

console.log( traverseTree(tree) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this has been brought back up, we might want to visit a simpler ES6 solution:

```js
const extract = (people = []) => 
  people .flatMap (({children = [], ... rest}) => [rest, ... extract (children)])

const people = [{name: "Joe", age: "21", children: [{name: "Smith", age: "42", children: []}, {name: "Gary", age: "21", children: [{name: "Jenifer", age: "23", children: [{name: "Dani", age: "32", children: []}, {name: "Max", age: "34", children: []}]}]}]}, {name: "Albert", age: "33", children: []}, {name: "Ron", age: "29", children: []}]

console .log (extract (people))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We implement a very simple (preorder) depth-first traversal of the hierarchy returning everything but the `"children"` property at each node.